# Changing input text value with Javascript doesn't change display

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the value of a text `input` field based on user actions.  I'm doing it like this:

```
document.getElementById(textFieldID).value = newValue;
```

It isn't quite working -- the original text in the field remains on the screen, unchanged.  However, when I submit the form, it behaves as though the value was indeed changed correctly.  (And a debug `alert` confirms that yup, I'm hitting that bit of the code and passing in the right field ID and text value.)  Anybody have any insights?  Is there something I need to be doing to redraw the `input` element?

---

**Edit:**  Per Jeff B's request, and per the fact that this seems to have everybody stumped, here's some relevant bits of code:

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
   function changeText(changeSelector)
   {
      var myindex  = document.getElementById(changeSelector+"Recent").selectedIndex;
      var SelValue = document.getElementById(changeSelector+"Recent").options[myindex].value;
      document.getElementById(changeSelector).value = SelValue;
      document.getElementById("historicalText").value = SelValue;
      document.getElementById("historicalTextSelect").value = changeSelector;
   }
</script>

<input onChange="updateScrollingPreview1217(this); return true;" type="text" id="crawlMsg1217" name="crawlMsg1217" size="60" maxlength="1000" value="">

<select id="crawlMsg1217Recent" name="crawlMsg1217Recent" onchange="javascript:changeText('crawlMsg1217');">
[options go here]
</select>
```

And that "onChange" handler isn't what's gumming up the works; I get the same behavior with or without it.

---

**Edit 2:**  It looks like the problem is being caused by "JSpell", a third-party spelling checker our product uses.  (I'm told that clients prefer using it to a spellcheck built into the browser; go figure.)  It appears to be slightly misconfigured on my test machine, so I'm going to try straightening that out and praying that it makes the problems go away.  If it doesn't ... should be interesting.

---

**Edit 3:**  Yup.  Fscking JSpell.  Just posted a complete answer for the sake of posterity, will accept it tomorrow when I'm allowed.  My thanks to everybody who tried to help; +1's all around, wish I could give more.

Comment: Tried this on more than just one web browser?  Could be a web browser bug/misbehavior.

Comment: That should work. Side note: `document.getElementById` is for getting elements by their `id` attribute. You seem to be suggesting that you are passing in the `name` attribute of the field. This will only work in IE<8 due to a bug.

Comment: Managu:  I'm getting the same behavior in IE6, IE7 (well, 8 in compatibility mode), IE8, and FF3.  Nice thought, but not my culprit here.

Comment: Crescent Fresh:  It IS the ID, sorry for the ambiguity; will change the sample code.  Yeah, everything I've seen says that ought to work, but it's failing in all the browsers I've tried it on, which implies to me I'm doing something legitimately stupid.

Comment: Is `textFieldID` unique on the page? If a hidden input is `textFieldID` and a text input has a different id then `newValue` would still POST the updated value.

Comment: pygorex1:  Nope.  Though you had me excited for a second there -- that would indeed explain the observed behavior perfectly.

Comment: Erm, by "nope" I meant "Nope, that's not the problem."  `textFieldID` IS unique on the page.

Comment: Can you post some more of the surrounding code, and some of the form code?

Comment: Can you please include the code for "updateScrollingPreview1217"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have confirmed that the culprit is indeed JSpell, and that the precise trouble spot is this line:

`window.onload=jspellInit;`

Despite the prayers mentioned in Edit 2 above, making sure it was configured correctly did NOT make the problem go away.  And this line is indispensable to JSpell's functionality.  I don't know if JSpell always hoses Javascript functionality this way, or if there's some sort of perfect storm of factors that's causing it to pick a fight with my page, but that is indeed the source of my problems.

My thanks to everybody who tried to help.  This was obviously a bit of a no-win in terms of getting the right answer, since it was caused by a component that was seemingly entirely unrelated and thus didn't get mentioned by me, but you at least confirmed that I was (in theory) doing things right and not simply going insane.

Answer (score 2):

Is the document's id actually "textFieldID" or is "textFieldID" a javascript variable that contains the ID of the text input to change?  If it is not a variable, I believe you should make it:

```
document.getElementById('textFieldID').value=newValue;
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's a variable, and I've confirmed a couple of different ways that it's being set properly.

Comment: Hmmm, well w/out seeing the full code it is really hard to troubleshoot.  A really poor way to address this would be to put a wrapper element around the text field element and then change the innerHTML of the wrapper element.

HTML:
<div id='wrapperDiv'><input id='whateverTheRealIDIs' type='text' value=''></div>

JS:
document.getElementById('wrapperDiv').innerHTML="<input id='"+textFieldID+"' type='text' value='"+newValue+"'>";

Comment: Eek! +1 for sneaking up on the problem from behind, but yeah, I think I'd rather just live with the bug than inflict this on the next person to work on the code.  :-)

Comment: Haha, agreed - I didn't like that solution either but in the absence of anything else I thought I would throw it out there.  I took that snippet you posted - commented out the historicalText/historicalTextSelect and created an empty function for updateScrollingPreview1217 - and it worked as expected http://pastebin.com/d4b9d9845.  I have to think that there is a conflict somewhere else.

Comment: Sounds like I'm left with commenting-out swaths of the code at random until it starts working, and then zero-in. Aiyee. Well, this is why they pay me the big^H^H^H adequate bucks.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to debug this without the context, since the code you have ought to work fine. Can you confirm that you've got the right node by doing something like:

```
document.getElementById(textFieldID).style.border = "4px solid red";
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything, which I'm not sure what to make of.  The debug `alert` calls seem to be indicating I have the right node; perhaps something else on the page is buggering-up that element's ability to redraw in general?

Comment: Your code provided above works fine. If it's not the JSpell plug-in fouling up the works, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

What does any other element on the page have a name attribute that is the same as the id?

> Internet Explorer 8 and later. In IE8
>   mode, getElementById performs a
>   case-sensitive match on the ID
>   attribute only. In IE7 mode and
>   previous modes, this method performs a
>   case-insensitive match on both the ID
>   and NAME attributes, which might
>   produce unexpected results. -
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437%28VS.85%29.aspx

Try alerting your the nodeName and id ofr the returned element and make sure its the input you expect.

Comment: No go.  That element has the same name and ID, but nothing else has that as its ID or name.  Alerting the ID, nodeName, and type of the object I fished out of getElementById all gave me the expected results; it's an input text object with the correct ID.

Comment: Have you tried using inputElement.setAttribute('value', myValue); ?

Answer (score 0):

Use div element instead of textfield. I had same problem, my textfield which is changed with another script wasnt get the right value. you can easily use any div element like textfield with some CSS. than you can get the value from div using innerHTML.